# Delphi 10.2 Tokyo BluetoothLE not detecting any devices

Tags: ios, delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I recently upgraded Delphi from Berlin to Tokyo, in Delphi 10.1 Berlin 
I can drop a `BluetoothLE` component connect a `OnEndDiscoverDevices` and once once I call `.DiscoverDevices(ATimeout: Integer)` after my timeout I get the devices in `OnEndDiscoverDevices` and it works perfectly, I pickup the devices in my office.

However, In 10.2 Tokyo when I do the same in `OnEndDiscoverDevices` I receive no devices.

I copied all bluetooth source code for Berlin, and compiled it in Tokyo, and then it works again.

XCode : 8.3.3
PAServer : 19.0
iOS SDK : 10.3.1
iOS Version : 10.3.1

Comment: Open an issue report with Embarcadero

Comment: Thanks will do, just wanted to make sure its not just something on my side

Answer (score 1):

This is a Google thing.  BLE now requires location permission, and you need to request that permission at run-time (used to be just in the manifest).